# Receive parameters from POST requests in JAX-RS

Tags: json, web-services, jax-rs

I have a method that accepts JSON in `POST` request. The only way to get parameters from `POST` requests is using `@FormParam`.

But I consume the webservice using Android and I have no HTML forms over there.

```java
@Path("/app")
public class WebApi {

    @POST
    @Path("/prog")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Res method(@FormParam("name") Res name){

        try{
            System.out.println("Id:" +name.getId());
            System.out.println("Name: "+name.getName());
            return name;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`Res` is an entity class:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Res {

    @XmlElement int id;
    @XmlElement String name;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters ommited
}
```

Please tell me the way to receive parameters from `POST` requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, form parameters is not the only way to send data in `POST` requests.

### Using [`@FormParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html)

When you use form parameters, need to consume them using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It doesn't matter wheter you have HTML forms in Android or not. The `Content-Type` header of your request should be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

For this situation, you would have something as following in your JAX-RS resource:

```java
@Path("/prog")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Res method(@FormParam("id") Integer id, @FormParam("name") String name) {
    ...
}
```

To consume the above defined endpoint, your request should be like:

```
POST /app/prog HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

id=1&name=Example
```

Please note that no Java class to wrap your parameters is necessary to receive the parameters in this situation.

### Using [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html)

If you prefer using a Java class to wrap your parameters, you could have the following:

```java
public class Res {

    @FormParam("id")
    private Integer id;

    @FormParam("name")
    private String name;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters ommited
}
```

And your resource method will be like:

```java
@Path("/prog")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Res method(@BeanParam Res res) {
    ...
}
```

To consume the above defined endpoint, your request should be like:

```
POST /app/prog HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

id=1&name=Example
```

### Consuming JSON

Instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, your endpoint can consume `application/json`.

To do so, your endpoint method will be as following:

```java
@Path("/prog")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Res method(Res res) {
    ...
}
```

Depending on your JSON provider, your model class can be just like:

```
public class Res {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters ommited
}
```

And the JSON will be sent in the request payload with `application/json` as `Content-Type`:

```
POST /app/prog HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter is contained in the request entity body as json you don't need to apply @FormParam annotation, normally jax-rs implementation must support an entity provider that will map the entity body to the parameter of your method. If it doesn't fit your needs you can set a custom provider.

Comment: can i pass two parameters in one post method directly?

Comment: The entity body is mapped to one parameter. Other parameters can appear, they should have specific annotations like QueryParam, FormParam.